# How to correctly handle a named index, when saving multiindex csv-files?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, multi-index

As I was used to doing with simple DataFrame tables, I wanted to add a name to the index of a table with multi-indices. For some reason then the importing that otherwise worked fine now throws an error.

I just want to get the same table back from the csv that I had when saving the csv.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong, or why this doesn't work as I expect?

In case it has to do with the csv, is there another text-based format that could be used instead?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# first example, everything works as expected
# df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10, 4)), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

# second example, read_csv() throws error - bug?
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10, 4)),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
                      ['A', 'B'],
                      ['x', 'y']
                  ]))

df.index.name = 'idx'
print(df)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col='idx')
print(df)
```

Comment: It's not your `index` that's `MultiIndex`... it's your columns, so `df.index.name = 'idx'` probably isn't doing what you expect. Does `pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=[0,1])` get what you need?

Comment: @ChrisA Yes I do indeed want to use the *columns* with MultiIndex, and `df.index.name = 'idx'` does seem to name the index-column (usualy enumerated 0,1,2,3,4,...) to `idx`, or is that wrong? I have to look up this `header` argument.

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=[0,1], index_col=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can pass `names` parameter to the `MultiIndex.from_product` method if you like and use the `header` parameter in the `read_csv` method to set your column `MultiIndex`. You can also pass `0` as your index_col here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10, 4)),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
                      ['A', 'B'],
                      ['x', 'y']
                  ], names=['level1', 'level2']))

df.index.name = 'idx'

df.to_csv('test.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=[0,1], index_col=0)
```

[out]

```
level1    A         B     
level2    x    y    x    y
idx                       
0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and the update), that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: So just in case someone else comes across this: It seems it is not possible to directly encode the whole DataFrame structure into a csv and recover it again without any additional information, if there MultiIndex is used. (Which actually makes sense considering how limited csv is.)